# How can I pass a UILabel as a URL in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel

I have a UILabel called `itemOneURL` which reads a URL from an external database and adds the value to this label as a string. I've got a separate button called `viewItemOne` (using a working segue) which once selected, will take the contents of the `itemOneURL` URL and open this link using the default browser. Here is the code I am currently using.

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemOneURL: UILabel!

@IBAction func viewItemOne(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    let firstURL = itemOneURL as? String
   
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"\(firstURL)")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    
}
```

However, once I select this button on the UI my application doesn't do anything, whereas when I use the following syntax elsewhere, it works and loads the URL?

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"https://stackoverflow.com")! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Is there something I am doing wrong which is currently causing the button to not perform any action once selected?

Comment: You want itemOneUrl.text

Comment: itemOneUrl is a label, not a String. The as? String won’t work.

Answer (score 2):

"How can I pass a UILabel as a URL in Swift?"

Short answer: Don't. Don't use view objects to store information.

Give your viewController a property `itemOneURL`.

Rename your label `itemOneURLLabel`. (Use the `refactor>rename` menu item and Xcode will rename every occurrence, including any outlet links in your storyboard(s) or XIB files.)

Add a didSet method to your itemOneURL variable:

```
var itemOneURL: String {
   didSet {
      itemOneURLLabel.text = itemOneURL
   }
}
```

Then, if you need the string URL value, it's in a String variable like it should be. Problem solved.